# Как получить высоту текста?

Tags: d3.js

```
// Выбираем элемент в котором создадим SVG
const svg_container = d3.select('#svg-container');
// Резервируем место
let svg = svg_container.selectAll('svg').data([null]);
let text = this.svg.selectAll(".text").data([null]);
```

Добавляю текст:

```
text.enter()
    .append('text')
    .merge(text)
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${this.svg_height}), rotate(90)`)
    .text('Высота')
    .attr('class', 'text')
    .attr('x', line1_y2)
    .attr('y', - line1_x2);

console.log(text.node().getBoundingClientRect());
```

Получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Я понимаю, что нету **ноды**, но мне нужна ширина текста для центрирования. Как мне это решить?

Comment: А что Вы пытаетесь центровать и где

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала я подозреваю что Вы делаете что-то не так, т.к. текст центровать нужно атрибутами узла `<text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central"`

---

```
let text = this.svg.selectAll(".text").data([null]);
```

В этом случае переменная `text` еще не ссылается на "Выборку", она ссылается на связку, выборка рождается после вызова `.enter()` `update()` `.exit()` и представляет из себя множество добавляемых, обновляемых или удаляемых узлов.

```
text = text.enter().append('text')
```

Затем "Выборка", содержит от 0 до n узлов, а Вы обращаетесь с ней как с одним узлом.

---

Вот код, который вызывает `getBoundingClientRect()` для всех текстовых нод во всех svg на странице.

```js
const svg_container = d3.select('#svg-container');

let svg = d3.selectAll('svg');
let text = svg.selectAll(".text").data([null]);

text = text.enter()
    .append('text')
    .merge(text)
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${100}), rotate(90)`)
    .text('Высота')
    .attr('class', 'text')
    .attr('x', d => 10)
    .attr('y', d => 10);

text.each(function(d) {
  console.log(this.getBoundingClientRect())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="200"></svg>
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="200"></svg>
```

---

Теперь лирическое отступление.

Смею предположить что Вы еще не разобрались с фундаментальной концепцией **D3** "связками" (**joins**) и "выборками" (**selections**).

Выборка это множество(можно о ней думать как о массиве) ячеек для элементов (может быть и 0), которая первоначально может быть получена при помощи методов `d3.select()` и `d3.selectAll()`. В ячейках выборки может и не быть элементов.

После применения к *выборке* метода `.data([...])` создается *связка*.

Связка это ассоциация данных с узлами в выборке. И она разбивается на 3 секции 
`.enter()` `update()` `.exit()`.

Каждая из них представлена новыми выборками:

`.enter()` - выборка ячеек, для данных, которым не хватило места среди ячеек прошлой выборки (ячейки не содержат узлов)

`.update()` - выборка ячеек, для данных, для которых было место среди ячеек прошлой выборки (ячейки содержат узлы)

`.exit()` - выборка ячеек, которые оказались лишними, для присоединяемых данных (ячейки содержат узлы)

Методы `.append()` `.style()` `.attr()` (их еще много), которые вы вызываете на выборке применяются ко всем элементам в ячейках этой выборки.

Вот статья ["Думайте связками"](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) от Mike Bostock, автора D3

На github у модуля [d3-selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection) тоже неплохая дока

PS: Если что-то не понятно спросите в комментах, data-join это ключевая концепция в d3 и без её понимания все будет очень смутно.

Comment: Не совсем тогда понял зачем используют метод `.merge`?

Comment: @doox911 он появился в d3v5, он объединяет выборки, в Вашем примере он не обязателен, его используют для обновления состояния, когда данные изменились, короче он объединяет выборки

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что значит не хватило места? Я так понимаю, что после выборки и создания связи с данными количество элементов выборки `=` количеству элементов данных. Это так? И если это так, то зачем вызывается метод `enter()`? И зачем нужны другие выборки, если обновления наступают после вызова метода `enter()` и явного добавления данных?

Comment: @doox911 он как раз возвращает только что созданные привязкой узлы, которых еще не было